# Add "show conky" button to ubuntu top bar

Tags: gnome-shell, conky

I'd like to add, next to bluetooth, wifi indicator, etc. another button that would bring conky to the front of opened windows.

Any tips? Googling didn't really help me much, only instructions how to set up conky.

My Ubuntu version is 18.04 my desktop enviroment is GNOME3.

Comment: You can modify your conky to behave like a normal window. If you minimize it, it will be in your dock. Whenever you need to view it above other windows, click on its icon in the dock. Then, when you're done, minimize it again.